# Duplicate permutation order for two separate matrices

Tags: r, permutation

I have two vectors, one for covariance and one for variance. I wish to do permutation testing for these two vectors, but I want to duplicate the randomization for both vectors. So say my covariance vector `Cov` is given by

```
Cov <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

and my variance vector `Var` is given by

```
Var <- c(20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55)
```

I can do 1000 permutations for `Cov` using the following:

```
P1000C <-c()
for (i in 1:1000){
  perm <- sample(Cov, replace=F)
  P1000C <- rbind(P1000C, perm)
}
rownames(P1000C) <- paste("Perm", 1:1000, sep = " ")
```

which will give me the matrix `P1000` with 1000 random permutations like below:

```
Perm 1       7  1  6  4  8  2  5  3
Perm 2       8  6  3  7  4  2  5  1
Perm 3       8  6  4  7  3  5  2  1
...
Perm 1000    5  7  2  6  4  1  8  3
```

Now my question is I want to create a permutation matrix for `Var` that gives 1000 permutations in the exact same order as in `P1000C`. I'll call this matrix `P1000V`, and I want it to look like this:

```
Perm 1       50  20  45  35  55  25  40  30
Perm 2       55  45  30  50  35  25  40  20
Perm 3       55  45  35  50  30  40  25  20
...
Perm 1000    40  50  25  45  35  20  55  30
```

So all the permutations in `P1000V` will be in the same order as those in `P1000C.`Is there a way to "imitate" a permutation in R?

Comment: wouldn't you get there by making explicit and storing the permutation matrix used, rather than making a call to the sample function that hides that from you? Some [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/pMatrix-class.html_ on what I'm thinking....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just build a matrix of the ordering of the indices (I'll draw just 10 samples in this case):

```
set.seed(144)
(perms <- t(replicate(10, sample(seq_along(Cov), replace=FALSE))))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#  [1,]    2    1    7    6    4    8    3    5
#  [2,]    3    6    7    2    4    5    8    1
#  [3,]    1    6    8    7    4    2    3    5
#  [4,]    8    6    3    4    2    7    1    5
#  [5,]    1    8    2    5    3    4    7    6
#  [6,]    4    5    1    6    7    3    8    2
#  [7,]    6    2    7    1    8    5    4    3
#  [8,]    8    3    5    6    1    4    2    7
#  [9,]    3    2    1    5    8    6    7    4
# [10,]    5    6    1    3    8    2    7    4
```

Note that this should be much more efficient than using a `for` loop and calling `rbind` to add one row at a time. To understand why this is the case, check out the second circle of [the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Now you can get the associated permutations of `Cov` and `Var` with:

```
matrix(Cov[perms], nrow=nrow(perms))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#  [1,]    2    1    7    6    4    8    3    5
#  [2,]    3    6    7    2    4    5    8    1
#  [3,]    1    6    8    7    4    2    3    5
#  [4,]    8    6    3    4    2    7    1    5
#  [5,]    1    8    2    5    3    4    7    6
#  [6,]    4    5    1    6    7    3    8    2
#  [7,]    6    2    7    1    8    5    4    3
#  [8,]    8    3    5    6    1    4    2    7
#  [9,]    3    2    1    5    8    6    7    4
# [10,]    5    6    1    3    8    2    7    4

matrix(Var[perms], nrow=nrow(perms))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#  [1,]   25   20   50   45   35   55   30   40
#  [2,]   30   45   50   25   35   40   55   20
#  [3,]   20   45   55   50   35   25   30   40
#  [4,]   55   45   30   35   25   50   20   40
#  [5,]   20   55   25   40   30   35   50   45
#  [6,]   35   40   20   45   50   30   55   25
#  [7,]   45   25   50   20   55   40   35   30
#  [8,]   55   30   40   45   20   35   25   50
#  [9,]   30   25   20   40   55   45   50   35
# [10,]   40   45   20   30   55   25   50   35
```